# JavaScript how to sort locale language along with english

Tags: javascript

```
function letterSort(lang, letters) {
  letters.sort(new Intl.Collator(lang).compare);
  return letters;
}
console.log(letterSort('zh', ['a','z','诶']));
// Actual output:  ["诶", "a", "z"]
// Expected output:  ["a", "z"," 诶" ]
```

I want English to be sorted first followed by Chinese
    Note : Chinese char also should be sorted

Comment: It's hard to tell what you need and the first line of your code doesn't even work , please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Code edited for your information

Answer (score 3):

You could first compare whether the two compared letters are from the same range, assuming that English is restricted to the first 256 characters in Unicode. When that is the case, use the appropriate comparator function, if not, put English first.

```js
function letterSort(lang, letters) {
  let cmp = new Intl.Collator(lang).compare;
  letters.sort((a, b) =>
    (a > "\xff") - (b > "\xff") || (a > "\xff" ? cmp(a, b) : a.localeCompare(b)) 
  );
  return letters;
}
console.log(letterSort('zh', ['a','z','诶', 'A', 'Z', '诵', '@', '1']));
```

Comment: Could you please explain if we assume English is restricted to first 256 unicode character, will it work with other locale like sv and da which has some English characters

Comment: When you use a language code that also use the Latin character set (like "sv" and "da"), it is ambiguous what the sort order would have to be, since most (or all) of the plain a-z letters are also valid in those languages. If you have a precise order in mind, then please update your question with that, and some examples. I will adapt my answer accordingly if it is clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

These characters are part of a range of universal characters, so called utf-8 (or maybe 16 or 32...)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Each one of these characters have a single hexadecimal value.

So in your case, extending your sort function to sort by ranges of those values should do the job.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the downvote ? I'm always glad to learn.

Comment: I did not downvote but UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32... are different encodings, and it is not really helpful when fact is that JavaScript works with one, specific encoding. Whether the encoding value is expressed as hexadecimal or not is irrelevant. Finally, extending the sort function is what the OP is looking for, but the information you provided is not really helping much in that direction.

Comment: Right, whatever the encoding, it doesn't matter in this specific case, you are right.
But then your answer is just the coded version of what I meant. 
You compare the hexadecimal value of every character using ranges based on locales.

Comment: Correction: I don't compare hexadecimal value; I compare values. Hexadecimal notation is irrelevant. And the way to code it is the key to the answer.